# How to use react slick slider with ssr?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server-side-rendering, slick.js

I use slick slider with react and ssr.
When rendering the slider on the server, for some reason,something is wrong, I don't lnow maybe styles are not loaded.Has anyone encountered a similar?

**SSR rendering**
[image: SSR remdering]

**client renderinng**
[image: client renderinng]

Comment: I am also facing this issue. How did you solve it?